# ssrs dynamic text color

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am using SSRS for MS-SQL 2008 R2.  I have a column of data that will display Active Staff, Inactive Staff, or Null.  I want to change the color of text in the column to red if they are Inactive Staff or Null.  I also want to change the Null to display "No Staff" in the column.  I can get one or the other to Red but not both and currently I have Inactive Staff.

The two expressions I am using to generate the column is:
For Column Value:

```
=IIF(IsNothing(Fields!StaffName.Value), 
      "No Staff", 
      Fields!StaffName.Value)
```

For color:

```
=IIF(Fields!StaffName.Value.ToString().Contains("Inactive"), "Red",
 IIF(ISNothing(Fields!StaffName.Value), "Red", 
 "Black"
 ))
```

Comment: Remember case sensitivity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made some guesses about your dataset and put together a simple example.

Dataset:

```
select StaffName = 'Staff 1'
union all select StaffName = 'Staff 2 (Inactive)'
union all select StaffName = null
```

Expression for **Text Box**, exactly the same as yours:

```
=IIf(IsNothing(Fields!StaffName.Value), "No Staff", Fields!StaffName.Value)
```

Expression for **Text Box** *Color* property:

```
=IIf(InStr(Fields!StaffName.Value, "Inactive") > 0 or IsNothing(Fields!StaffName.Value)
    , "Red"
    , "Black")
```

End result:

[image]

`@Preet Sangha` made a good point in his comment, too, so you may need to bear case sensitivity in mind.

Comment: Remember that SSRS is also used for other data sources such as SSAS so it's not always certain that SQL is the query language. But I agree that sometimes it's easier to mangle the query, or it's fields) than expressions in the report This is the real beauty of SSRS - the level of customisation offered.